# How to assign an interface to a useFetch object Vuejs 3 and Nuxtjs 3

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3

How to assign an interface to a useFetch  object Vuejs 3

Interface

```
export interface ProdutoInterface {
  codigo: number
  nome: string
}
```

Componente

```
const { data: produto, error } = await useFetch(config.API_BASE_URL+`/produto`)
```

I can't get it to work. Would anyone know how to help me.

thank you very much for your attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use fetch accepts an generic type:

```
const { data: produto, error } = await <ProdutoInterface>useFetch(config.API_BASE_URL+`/produto`)
```